# How to match column values of one table with column Name another table pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have two dataframes

dataframe_1

| Id | qname | qval |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Mango | [100,200] |
| 01 | Banana | [500,400,800] |

dataframe_2

| reqId | Mango | Banana | Orange | Apple |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 100 | 500 | NULL | NULL |
| 1001 | 200 | 500 | NULL | NULL |
| 1002 | 200 | 800 | NULL | NULL |
| 1003 | 900 | 1100 | NULL | NULL |

Expected Result

| Id | ReqId |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 1000 |
| 01 | 1001 |
| 01 | 10002 |

Please give me some idea. I need to match all qname and value of dataframe_1 to the columns of dataframe_2, ignoring the NULL columns of dataframe_2. Get all the reqId from dataframe_2.

Note - All qname and val of a particular id of dataframe_1 should match with all the columns of dataframe_2, ignoring nulls. For example, id -01 , has two qname and val. These two should match with corresponding column names of dataframe_2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is:

- In df2, for each column, pair "reqId" with the column.
- In df2, introduce a dummy column with some constant value and group by this column so all values are in one group.
- Unpivot df2.
- Join df1 and above processed df2.
- For each element in "qval" list, filter corresponding "reqId" from joined df2 column.
- Group by "id" and explode "reqId".

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["01","Mango",[100,200]],["01","Banana",[500,400,800]],["02","Banana",[800,1100]]], schema=["Id","qname","qval"])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=[[1000,100,500,None,None],[1001,200,500,None,None],[1002,200,800,None,None],[1003,900,1100,None,None]], schema="reqId int,Mango int,Banana int,Orange int,Apple int")

for c in df2.columns:
  if c != "reqId":
    df2 = df2.withColumn(c, F.array(c, "reqId"))

df2 = df2.withColumn("dummy", F.lit(0)) \
         .groupBy("dummy") \
         .agg(*[F.collect_list(c).alias(c) for c in df2.columns]) \
         .drop("dummy", "reqId") 

stack_cols = ", ".join([f"{c}, '{c}'" for c in df2.columns])
df2 = df2.selectExpr(f"stack({len(df2.columns)},{stack_cols}) as (qval2, qname2)")

@F.udf(returnType=ArrayType(IntegerType()))
def compare_qvals(qval, qval2):
  return [x[1] for x in qval2 if x[0] in qval]
# 

df_result = df1.join(df2, on=(df1.qname == df2.qname2)) \
               .withColumn("reqId", compare_qvals("qval", "qval2")) \
               .groupBy("Id") \
               .agg(F.flatten(F.array_distinct(F.collect_list("reqId"))).alias("reqId")) \
               .withColumn("reqId", F.explode("reqId"))
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+
|Id |reqId|
+---+-----+
|01 |1000 |
|01 |1001 |
|01 |1002 |
|02 |1002 |
|02 |1003 |
+---+-----+
```

PS - To cover case with multiple "Id"s, I have added some extra data to the sample dataset, hence output has some extra rows.